# How can I filter iron out of kiddie pool water?

Tags: water, pool, filter

Our well water is high in iron. In the house, we put salt with an iron remover into our water softener. The outside bibs don't run through the water softener, however. The other day we filled up the kiddie pool for the first time and after a while the water turned orange.

Is there any way to either filter the iron out or to prevent the water from turning orange?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have this exact same problem. The only option I have found is to use a chemical additive to precipitate out the the iron and then do lots of filter cartridge changes. Luckily, the cartridges don't seem to be deteriorated by the orange stuff, and you can just swap two of them every 12 hours and wash them off with the garden hose. If you have a full size filter, you will just need to do a backwash every day or two.

It also helps to get in the pool and stir up all the precipitate off the bottom so that it can be captured by the filter...there's nothing in there that will harm you, it's just orange.

Comment: This is a very small kiddie pool, so there is no filter. I've heard of hose filters, but have not been able to find any. What chemicals do you use? I thought of Iron Out, but their FAQ says not to use in pool water.

Comment: Hmmm....without a filter, I'm not sure what other options there are. You can get iron/metals remover from almost anywhere. Walmart carries several http://www.walmart.com/ip/Blue-Wave-Products-Super-Rust-and-Scale-Remover-Pack-of-4/20959102 so does Amazon http://www.amazon.com/Metal-Free-Chemical-Liter-Natural-Chemistry/dp/B002ZJ3HZO/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1340722840&sr=8-4&keywords=pool+metal+remover

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could make a filter for your pool. Lowes has a couple of products that should do the trick. This would be used in conjunction with the iron precipitating additives that DaveNay suggested.

[Whirlpool Sediment Filter](http://www.lowes.com/ProductDisplay?partNumber=89376-59019-WHKF-DWHV&langId=-1&storeId=10151&productId=1201343&catalogId=10051&cmRelshp=req&rel=nofollow&cId=PDIO1)
I like the clear housing so you can easily see how dirty the filter is.

[image: Whirlpool Sediment Filter]

[Submersible Fountain Pump](http://www.lowes.com/ProductDisplay?partNumber=58695-60084-FP155&langId=-1&storeId=10151&productId=3036184&catalogId=10051&cmRelshp=req&rel=nofollow&cId=PDIO1)
[image: Submersible Fountain Pump]

Answer (score 2):

You could use [an adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000KKOYSY) to attach the garden hose to an inside faucet.

[image]